# Как в JSF перед отправкой формы вызвать метод JS?

Tags: javascript, form, jsf, primefaces

Использую `PrimeFaces`. Хочу, чтобы перед отправкой формы происходила проверка js методом. И в зависимости от возвращаемого js функцией значения, данные формы отправлялись или нет.
Есть форма

```
<h:form id="create_account" >
    ....
    <h:commandButton id="formsubmit" action="reg" value="Регистрация"/>                       
</h:form>
```

Далее, есть js-функция `registration()`

```
function registration() {
if (($('.captcha_wrap ul').validate()) == false) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}}
```

Можно ли, и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойство onclick:

```
<h:commandButton id="formsubmit" onclick="return registration()" action="reg" value="Регистрация"/>
```

Если `registration()` возвращает `false`, то `action` не вызывается; если `true` - то `action` выполнится.

PS В `Primefaces` есть готовый компонент [Captcha](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml), думаю, что он гораздо гармоничнее впишется в код JSF-страницы.

Comment: почему-то `onclick="return registration()"` не влияет на отправку формы. Хотелось бы всё-таки использовать свою каптчу :)

Comment: Преложенное мной решение - рабочее, я проверил сам. Если не работает, значит проблема где-то у вас. Создайте тестовую страницу, на которой не будет ничего из того, что у вас скрыто за "....", в теле функции registration() сделайте просто return false;, чтобы исключить возможность проблем в других частях страницы.
<h:form id="create_account">
            <h:commandButton id="formsubmit" onclick="return registration()" action="registration.xhtml" value="Регистрация"/>
        </h:form>
<script type="application/javascript">
function registration() {
  return false;
}
</script>

Comment: В таком варианте работает, однако, применяя к моему коду - нет. Вот содержимое формы:

Comment: `<h:form id="create_account"><h:message id="message_usernamesignup" for="usernamesignup"/>
<h:inputText id="usernamesignup" value="#{registrationUser.name}" pt:placeholder="Имя" styleClass="panelGridhInputText">
<f:ajax event="blur" render="message_usernamesignup"/></h:inputText>
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{registrationUser.password}" pt:placeholder="Пароль"></h:inputSecret> <h:message id="m_password" for="password"  /><div class="captcha_wrap"></div><h:commandButton id="formsubmit" class="reg_button" onclick="return registration();" action="reg"  value="Регистрация"/></h:form>`

Comment: Да, вы, правы, это работает и дело не в том, что в форме, а в функции js. Простой пример `function registration() { if (true) {return false; } else { return true;  } }` работает. Видимо, проблема кроется в обработке, которую использую в этой функции

Comment: Решила проблему. Правда не знаю почему оно начало работать. Сделала следующее: перенесла объявления js-функции `validate` в страницу, где ниже вызываю её из registration(): `if ($('.captcha_wrap ul').validate() == false) {   return false; } else {return true;}`. Также в методе `validate` после после каждого `&` пишу `amp;`. Проблема была внутри `validate()`